# How to decompile python 2.4 bytecode?

Tags: python, byte-code

I need a good decompiler that can decompile python 2.4 byte code. I have looked over the internet and can only find python 2.5+

There are about a few hundred `.pycs`, so if it can decompile a directory it would be nice.

Note: Easy Python Decompiler is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to search online.
Anyways here are some python 2.4 decompilers worth trying,

- decompyle - http://murphey.org/code/decompyle-2.4.tgz
- pycdc - https://github.com/zrax/pycdc
- depython - http://depython.com/
- decompyle service - http://www.crazy-compilers.com/decompyle/
- Python-Decompiler - https://gitorious.org/python-decompiler

<sub>Note : Easy Python Decompiler (written by me) uses pycdc as the backend.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfect open-source Python (.PYC) decompiler, called Decompyle++ https://github.com/zrax/pycdc/

Decompyle++ aims to translate compiled Python byte-code back into valid and human-readable Python source code. While other projects have achieved this with varied success, Decompyle++ is unique in that it seeks to support byte-code from any version of Python.

Online version is also available: http://www.javadecompilers.com/pyc
(currently non-functional)